# Mapping this json to java object (pojo)

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have to map a json which would look like this, it's basicly an object, which can contain the same object again as a child, then that one can also contain the same object again. How would i be able to map this to java pojo's?

This is the json:

```
    {
"group": [
            {
                "name": "Beheerders",
                "desc": "Beheerders",
                "children" : [
                    "group" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Beheerders",
                            "desc": "Beheerders"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Beheerders",
                            "desc": "Beheerders"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Beheerders",
                            "desc": "Beheerders"
                            "children": [
                                "group" : [
                                {
                                    "name": "Beheerders",
                                    "desc": "Beheerders"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Beheerders",
                                    "desc": "Beheerders"
                                }
                        }

            }
        ]
    }
```

And i have these 4 pojo's:

Group.java

```
        private String name;
        private String desc;
        private Children children;

//getters & Setters & toString
```

GroupList.java

```
 private ArrayList<Group> group;

    public void setGroup(ArrayList<Group> group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public ArrayList<Group> getGroup() {
        return this.group;
    }
```

Children.java

```
   private ArrayList<ChildrenGroup> group;

    public ArrayList<ChildrenGroup> getGroup() {
        return this.group;
    }

    public void setGroup(ArrayList<ChildrenGroup> group) {
        this.group = group;
    }
```

childrengroup.java

```
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private Children Children;

//Getters & Setters & toString
```

This is not working for me, i always get this error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Your JSON is not valid and your objects aren't correctly using object vs List. Please validate your example JSON. You can also possibly remove Children and ChildrenGroup and just nest GroupList insideGroup. `"children" : [ "group" : [` is invalid as well.

Comment: Reworked the json to a valid json and used only the group and grouplist classes and things are now working! Tnx a lot! if you make your comment an answer i could mark it as answered

Comment: Glad to be of help. I copied my comment into an answer and tried to explain a bit more as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid and your objects aren't correctly using object vs List. Please validate your example JSON. `"children" : [ "group" : [` is invalid.

Your errors are occurring because it is encountering `[` when your java objects are specifying `{`.

You can remove Children and ChildrenGroup and just nest GroupList inside Group as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tools like [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate POJO from your JSON.

If I'm understanding correctly you are trying to convert smth like the following:

```
{
  "g":[
    {
      "a":"1",
      "c":"2"
    },
    {
      "a":"2",
      "c":"3",
      "d":[
        {
          "g":[
            {"a":"3",
            "c":"4"},
            {"a":"5",
            "c":"6"}
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The output for this one will be:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.D.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class D {

private List<G_> g = null;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public List<G_> getG() {
return g;
}

public void setG(List<G_> g) {
this.g = g;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

private List<G> g = null;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public List<G> getG() {
return g;
}

public void setG(List<G> g) {
this.g = g;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.G.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class G {

private String a;
private String c;
private List<D> d = null;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getA() {
return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
this.a = a;
}

public String getC() {
return c;
}

public void setC(String c) {
this.c = c;
}

public List<D> getD() {
return d;
}

public void setD(List<D> d) {
this.d = d;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.G_.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class G_ {

private String a;
private String c;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getA() {
return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
this.a = a;
}

public String getC() {
return c;
}

public void setC(String c) {
this.c = c;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Comment: Wow tnx a lot for that tool, super handy and never heard of such tools! This is going to make my life easier